# is it possible to add lables for services when deploying helm charts?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-label

I am trying to deploy mysql server with the help of [bitnami helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql).

The chart seems to create two services (mysql & mysql-headless) and I want to add a unique lable to the mysql-headless

with kubectl it is straight forward as following:

```bash
kubectl label service mysql-headless consul.hashicorp.com/service-ignore="true"
```

I did try to change the `podLables` for the values.ymal but it didn't work. Adding in `commonLabels` did work, but then it is added to both services.

**values.yml**

```yaml
commonLabels: { "consul.hashicorp.com/service-ignore": "true" }

secondary:
  podAntiAffinityPreset: hard
  podLabels: { "consul.hashicorp.com/service-ignore": "true" }
```

is there anyway to achive this by editing values file for the helm chart?

Please note that I am deploying the charts with terraform.

```
resource "helm_release" "mysql" {

  name          = "mysql"
  repository    = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart         = "mysql"
  version       = "9.1.2"
  values        = [file("${path.module}/helm/values.yml")]
  namespace     = var.namespace
  recreate_pods = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually look at the [Helm template for the headless service](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mysql/templates/primary/svc-headless.yaml#L6-L10) it only has the standard labels and the `.Values.commonLabels`

```yaml
  labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
    {{- if .Values.commonLabels }}
    {{- include "common.tplvalues.render" ( dict "value" .Values.commonLabels "context" $ ) | nindent 4 }}
    {{- end }}
```

So without modifying the chart or using a [post renderer](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering), there's no way to set a label for the headless service but not the main service.